# error with loop in jade

Tags: html, loops, pug

I want to use loop in jade. I have pointed where the problem occurs in code below.
The problem is that i want the class name to be "thumb-unit-1", "thumb-unit-2" and so on.
But i get class name as "thumb-unit-#{i+1}" after compiled.
I am using sublime text 3. And for compiler i am using prepros.

```
-var work = ["Typo International Design Talks", "city-in website concept", "crispy icons", "flat mobile ui/ux concept", "fresh it up", "timeline page", "weather dashboard", "stripes & co"]

-for (var i=0; i<8; i++){
    a(href="",class="thumb-unit-#{i+1}") //problem here
        div(class="thumb-overlay")
            strong #{work[i]}
-}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

```
-var work = ["Typo International Design Talks", "city-in website concept", "crispy icons", "flat mobile ui/ux concept", "fresh it up", "timeline page", "weather dashboard", "stripes & co"]

-for (var i=0; i<8; i++){
    a(href="",class="thumb-unit-"+[i+1]) //solution here
        div(class="thumb-overlay")
            strong #{work[i]}
-}
```